# Jira API does not work while using for create issue

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm develop an chrome extension for jira which get a data from a DIV element of another website and use the data to raise a jira ticket by my chrome extension automatically. 
the issue is when I call below jira api in my code I faced below error

```
content.js:107 POST http://myjira.com:9090/rest/api/2/issue/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

but as I checked my request in Post Man app everything is fine and new ticket raise in Jira.
I'm really appreciated if someone can help me to fix the issue.
moreover, I used my personal computer and the jira is on another server.
totally I want to have a extension to integrate a ticketing system with jira, without access to that site. 
please have following code.
content.js

$(document).ready(function () {

```
var key = '';
var summary = 'undefined';
var description = '';
var comment = '';
window.setInterval(function () {
    /// call your function here


    console.log($('Div1').html());
    console.log($('Div2').html());
    console.log($('#Div3').html());
    console.log($('Div4').html());


    key = $('.a span:first').html();
    summary = $('#b').html();
    description = $('#r'')').html();
    comment = $('#u').html();

    if (summary == 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "fields": {
            "project": {
                "key": "RTF"
            },
            "summary": "" + summary + "",
            "description":  "" + description + "",
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/issuetype/10111",
                "id": "10111",
                "description": "Service Request",
                "iconUrl": "http:/myjira.com/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10720&avatarType=issuetype",
                "name": "MS Task (SR)",
                "subtask": false,
                "avatarId": 10720
            },
            "customfield_10106": {
                "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10476",
                "value": "EMAIL",
                "id": "10476"
            },
            "customfield_10129": [
                {
                    "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10450",
                    "value": "TEST",
                    "id": "10450"
                }
            ],
            "customfield_10188": [
                {
                    "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10469",
                    "value": "Billing",
                    "id": "10469"
                }
            ],
            "customfield_10180": {
                "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/11000",
                "value": "Support",
                "id": "11000"
            },
            "assignee": {
                "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/user?username=e.pirjahandideh",
                "name": "e.jj",
                "key": "e.jj",
                "emailAddress": "e.jj@jj.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/68e54d1c135e85b994eb12cb9a3b7b9b?d=mm&s=48",
                    "24x24": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/68e54d1c135e85b994eb12cb9a3b7b9b?d=mm&s=24",
                    "16x16": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/68e54d1c135e85b994eb12cb9a3b7b9b?d=mm&s=16",
                    "32x32": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/68e54d1c135e85b994eb12cb9a3b7b9b?d=mm&s=32"
                },
                "displayName": "Emil jj",
                "active": true,
                "timeZone": "Asia/Tehran"
            },
            "components": [
                {
                    "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/component/10071",
                    "id": "10071",
                    "name": "RR",
                    "description": "Managed RR"
                }
            ],
            "customfield_10189": {
                "self": "http://myjira.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10489",
                "value": "RR/IT",
                "id": "10489"
            }
        }
    });
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });
    xhr.open("POST", "myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic dasfasegsdfgsdfgsdfg");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "c6475a5e-6741-6894-5b8e-2350c7c5a176");
    xhr.send(data);
}, 10000);
```

});

manifest.json

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "Description",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "http://myjira.com/",
    "http://ticketing2.com"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": [
        "jquery.js",
        "jquery-ui.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ],

      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }

  ]

}
```

Comment: I probably don't remember enough about JIRA but have you tried POSTing to `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: yes, but same error

Comment: In that case please also post the full error object you get back from the query. JIRA generally has pretty verbose errors and the stack they return might shed some light to this situation.

Comment: @rorschach the exact error is content.js:107 POST http://myjira.com:9090/rest/api/2/issue/ 403 (Forbidden) from console

Comment: Yes, that's the error but open up the Network tab and add the full response object to this post.

Comment: Do it in your background script (i.e. the content script sends a message, the bg script does the network requests and sends data back to the content script).